# What is the difference between using meet.jit.si and JaaS?

Tags: jitsi, video-conferencing

I am making a video conferencing application using the Jitsi Android SDK.

I may use either the *meet.jit.si* server as a media gateway to a JaaS (Jitsi as a Service) from [8x8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8x8) corporation. What are pros and cons of those?

Answer (score 0):

In very simple words meet.jit.si is for public use for doing video conferencing for personal use, we don't need to host anything to use their app, we can start a person meeting just click of button-like google meet. while JaaS (Jitsi as a Service) from 8x8 is like the PaaS which provides backend microservices to support our self-hosted Jitsi.